# what happens when shell script is built in bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am just tying to understand the `bitbake` build system. I have a doubt regarding how shell functions/task gets executed. I am going through below documentation https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/

In a part of documentation it says shell scripts are executed by `/bin/sh`. In another part of documentation it says "BitBake writes a shell script to ${T}/run.do_taskname.pid and then executes the script".

What is `run.do_taskname.pid`? what exactly does it do? What exactly happens when `bitbake` encounters a shell script?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Did you read it at all? Are you alive?

Comment: @Philippos hello sir.i m here.i read ur answer immediately when u posted.it gave me a better insight into the build process.thank you.i have few more queries like whether run.xxx script will be created for each tasks individually or is it common for all tasks?i am yet to make a build.i will do it and after that i ill get back if i have further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably read that the build process has steps like *fetch*, *unpack*, *patch*, *configure*, *compile*, *deploy* and many more. Each step is executed as a shell script.

If you have a look in your build folder, in `tmp/work/<system>/<package>/<version>/temp` you find the said scripts like `run.do_fetch` with and without dot-appended process id.

In normal life, you don't care at all. But once you write your own recipes or just some patch added with your own `.bbappend` fails with a strange message, it may help to read what actually is executed during that step.

Internally, these files help the build system keep track of what to execute again after any change.